# vim expanded makeprg variable

Tags: vim

I use the `:set makeprg` functionality to set different make behaviour depending on files. One feature of this is that I can use `%` and `%<` in order to refer to the file in the active buffer, as well as `$` for environment variables.

I'd like to echo the *expanded* `makeprg` variable, but I can't seem to achieve this.

For example, suppose I have `:set makeprg=build\ %`, and I'm working on file `Foo.txt`.
I would expect the output of echoing an expanded `makeprg` to be:

```
build Foo.txt
```

However, we have the following result when echoing the `&makeprg` variable:

```
:echo(&makeprg)
build\ %
```

The solution probably involves using `expand()`, except that this would involve parsing the `&makeprg` for escaped symbols and dealing with `$` appropriately for environment variables. Is there a solution to this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need this? For troubleshooting, I would probably just append `echo` to `'makeprg'` (that's a trailing space after `\`):

```
:setl makeprg^=echo\
```

But the following should do what you had in mind. The trick is to split the `'makeprg'` string on spaces, and process each word individually:

```
:echo join(map(split(&makeprg), 'expand(v:val)'))
```

Comment: I simplified when I said I wanted to echo the expanded `makeprg`. I'm actually interested in this in order to execute `:call VimuxRunCommand (&makeprg)`, or similar, to fire off an async process that performs the `makeprg` for me outside of vim.

Comment: `join(map(split(&makeprg), 'expand(v:val)'))` works beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A bit closer to the truth:
`join(map(split(mystring, '\ze[<%#]'), 'expand(v:val)'), '')`.